# JavaScript Allow various functions to execute only if some condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of event handlers that are attached to various elements, but I want to disable *some* of them when a certain condition is true. This condition (i.e. boolean value) changes dynamically and it is not predictable when it changes. Here is what I do currently.

```
function foo () {
    if (someCondition) {
        return;
    }

    // foo does something
}

function bar () {
    if (someCondition) {
        return;
    }

    // bar does something
}

...etc
```

This is alright, but it's really redundant to have the if block in each function. Is there a more concise way to manage this? I was wondering if I can attach two event handlers to one element, and only execute one if the other returned true.

Comment: Your approach is fine as it is, in my opinion. It's not a lot of code, it's clear to a new reader, and it leaves open the possibility of changing the condition on a per-function basis. You can even condense it down to a single line without affecting readability.

Comment: Right, I agree that it is probably not wrong to do this way. I just personally feel more organized if I can avoid writing the same lines of code multiple times. I'm sure there are situations where that would be necessary, but I would first look for a more concise way.

Comment: It's a nice idea to want to centralize the decision making. If your application evolves such that the decision gets more complicated, you'd have to change it in a lot of places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a function that turns a function into one that only runs if the condition is true:

```
function conditionalize( fn ) {
  return function() {
    if (someCondition) return;
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

Then:

```
var foo = conditionalize(function() {
  // stuff that foo does
});
```

Comment: As mentioned `foo` and `bar` are event handlers, and in event handlers context `this` points to target element not global object

Comment: i removed my comment, i see why! Thx Pointy!

Comment: you should use `apply` function not `call`

Comment: @ABFORCE wow I read your comment and thought, "gee this person's nuts because I **did** use `apply`", and then I looked :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a delegate approach like jQuery event handling approach, try this:

```
var callbacks = [foo, bar];

function delegate() { // this is the only event handler
    var i, len;
    for(i=0, len = callbacks.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(callbacks[i].apply(this, arguments)){
            continue; // return value of this callback is true then continue
        } else {
            break; // ignore other callbacks
        }
    }
}

function foo () {
    // foo does something
}

function bar () {
    // bar does something
}
```